# Display pygame timer

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a game in pygame which includes a timer which stops when the player dies. However, I am having some problems displaying the timer on the screen, rather in the python shell. Hope you can help me out :D

```
pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 30)
text = font.render("Time", True, color)

running=True
while running:
    event = pygame.event.wait ()
    if pygame.sprite.colliede_rect(block, block1):
        window.blit(text, (window_width/2, window_height/2-100))
        pygame.display.update()
        print("du overlevede",pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000, "sekunder")  
        pygame.time.wait(5000)
        running = False
```

Comment: And what is the detailed error message? Please provide more information regarding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must render the text Surface every time you want to use it:

```
pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 30)

running=True
while running:
    event = pygame.event.wait ()
    if pygame.sprite.colliede_rect(block, block1):
        time_string = "Time du overlevede {} sekunder".format(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000)
        text = font.render(time_string, True, color)

        window.blit(text, (window_width/2, window_height/2-100))
        pygame.display.update()

        pygame.time.wait(5000)
        running = False
```

Comment: @user3601885 no problem and welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, you may want to provide more detail into your problem, such as what version of python, pygame, and other modules you are running, enough code to run on its own and reproduce the problem, very specifically what your program does vs what you want it to do, a full error traceback if applicable (not here), and in general as much information as you have on the problem. In this case I saw the problem in your code but it often not so simple.